# Stoppingtimes: Why demand $\mathbb{E}[\tau]<\infty$?

Tags: markov-chains, stopping-times

I'm working with a discrete-time Markov Chain $\{Y_j, j \geq 0 \}$  that evolves untill a stoppingtime $\tau$ is reached. $X$ is een stochastic variable which depends on the state of the Markov Chain.
I want to estimate $\mathbb{E}[X|Y_0]$ and to do that I use Importance Sampling.

It is assumed that $\mathbb E[\tau] < \infty$, but I don't understand why we need this assumption. Please help

Sincerely
MKTEL

Comment: Probably to guarantee that $X$ is integrable. Due to lack of details it is difficult to say more.

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean with that? I know I have not provided you with a lot of information but this is the only information I have.

Answer (score 1):

The reason one asks that $\tau$ is integrable is probably to ensure that $X$ is integrable, which is needed if one wants to consider the conditional expectation $\mathbb E[X\mid Y_0]$. But the lack of details in the question makes it difficult to say more.